# Compiling windows binaries from Ubuntu?

Tags: c, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I am doing a cross-platform C (not ++) game with both linux (main) and windows (alternate) binaries.
Until now I used devcpp to compile in windows, but I have trouble getting some libraries to work right, and I heard it is possible to compile a windows binary from withing Linux.
However, I don't know where to get started. 
The game uses a few libraries (GLEW, GL, SDL, SDL_mixer, SDL_image and Lua 5.1) that would clutter the distribution directory though, so is it possible to make a static binary with that method?

Comment: Take a look at the [Mingw](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LinuxCrossMinGW) compiler.

Comment: What is the game? Also I use ubuntu linux as my primary OS so I'm happy to hear this, but wouldn't it be prudent to design primarily for windows due to the vastly larger userbase?

Comment: Looks like this is what I need. Can it build static binaries?

Comment: Yes it can. Ubuntu keeps mingw in their repos too.

Comment: Already solved in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033997/how-to-compile-for-windows-on-linux-with-gcc-g

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compile for Windows on Linux with gcc/g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033997/how-to-compile-for-windows-on-linux-with-gcc-g)