# Compile Windows C console applications in Linux

Tags: c, windows, ubuntu

Can I compile a Windows C console application (.exe) in Linux? (more specific, Ubuntu)

I heard a long time ago of cross-compilers, but I wasn't interested in them at that time.

Best regards

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=22879) which gives some info, as well as this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702945/compiling-windows-binaries-from-ubuntu)

As you are using Ubuntu, the packages you need is (I think) `mingw32`

```
apt-get install mingw32
```

Then compile with i586-mingw32msvc-gcc, e.g.

```
i586-mingw32msvc-gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld.exe
```

Comment: Best answer so far, and yes, there was a dupe :D Also nice to post the needed packages. Straight answer, to the punch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also sorry for the duplicate question, I didn't spot it. :-)

Keep up the good work!

Thanks again.

Comment: On Fedora, we also have resources for learning about compiling for win32 using mingw, an irc channel, the mingw32 utilities and a bunch of pre-built libraries for windows -- for more info, see: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SIGs/MinGW .

Answer (score 3):

You can if it's standard C, and doesn't use Windows libraries.

C code itself is very portable, and the standard C libraries (libc) are available pretty much everywhere. If your code does printf() and sscanf() and fopen() and so on, then it will just compile and run on another platform.  Windows, Linux, BSD, etc.

It's the  libraries *other* than libc that introduce portability challenges.

Anything that links with Windows-specific platform libraries is trouble.  Kernel32.lib, user32.lib, etc etc.

There are third-party libs, too, that, if written in C, should be available across Linux and Windows.  PCRE is a good example here - it's a Regular Expression library written in C, and it's available on Windows as well as on Linux.  there are literally hundreds of libraries in this set.

If you confine yourself to libc and library calls into portable libs, then you will have a portable C application.

Comment: I've compiled GUI apps on for windows on linux before, I used the GTK gui toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a strictly ANSI C application, then you shouldn't have any problem compiling with gcc on a Linux platform.

If you're liking in to Windows System libraries, you're hosed and would have to replace those calls with their *nix System equivelants (if there are any).

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to compile a program from Linux into a Windows executable, yes cross compilers would be an option. http://www.airs.com/ian/configure/configure_5.html helped me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean can you build a windows .exe on Linux (ie develop on linux and deliver the app to Windows users?)

Or do you mean take a Windows app and recompile (port) it to Linux so it's built and runs on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/) and install VS for example .Other solution use [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/).
also you cans use cross compilers like [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Cross compiling is possible. AFAIK you get a windows executable, which of course will run under windows (and possibly WINE).

There are 2 possible choices for that: mingw and cygwin.

One tutorial [here](http://www.astro.gla.ac.uk/~paulm/Cross/).
MingW cross compile page is [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LinuxCrossMinGW).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use standard gcc in terminal of linux , you can use same programs you need only to change the std.h with unistd.h (meaning you will need to change to linux specific libraries).
I have a course about linux programming at school it except it's on ubuntu and library changes for input/output and some thread related linux specific ,all it's the same

example : gcc -c myprogram.c // to compile
          gcc -o myprogram.o name to make lib
          myprogram // with arguments if there are any