# How to compile C++ on linux for to make a windows binary

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, binary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Howto compile for Windows on Linux with gcc / g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033997/howto-compile-for-windows-on-linux-with-gcc-g)

We don't have windows here how can  I compile this program for some ppl?  Is there some kinda Wine for linux programs to run on windows or what.

Comment: Downvoting this was wrong by whoever did it, it's a perfectly valid question. And the answer is cross-compiling with mingw. I don't have enough reputation to answer within 3 minutes...

Comment: Usually, it's just better to distribute source code. Plus, it's funny to watch Windows users struggling to get things to compile on "Visual C++" ;)

Comment: @Aviral Dasgupta : `Usually, it's just better to distribute source code. Plus, it's funny to watch Windows users struggling to get things to compile on "Visual C++" ;) – Aviral Dasgupta` : This is one of the most childish comments I saw on StackOverflow. And I'm not even counting the clueless remark about the reality of the difficulty to compile on Visual C++, or the fact your comment doesn't help the question author whatsoever. Congrats.

Comment: @paercebal That's why it's a comment and not an answer. I'm talking about generic written-for-linux programs.

Comment: @Tobias - I wasn't the first person to down vote, but I did downvote because it shows little research effort - the top 4 hits for "linux build for windows" on google were all relevant and helpful.

Answer (score 6):

You can use cross-compiler `gcc-mingw`

I did not use it myself and about it only theoretically.

Comment: oh this is a Qt app i think it may use gcc-mingw natively?  I just drop a .exe on the output program and distribute mingw dll with it?

Comment: @user1139252 You need a [cross-compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler). A cross compiler is a compiler capable of creating executable code for a platform other than the one on which the compiler is run.