# is it possible to develop an app for windows using linux environment?

Tags: linux, windows, cross-platform

I am very new to this, so please pardon my illknowledge. I want to develop a simple timer GUI for windows but development shall be done on Linux? 
Any suggestions and comments on is this possible and how challenging it can be for a beginner?

Comment: Generally speaking yes it is possible but [so] is not really a place to ask for tutorials and alike. Try google your question, you should find many guides out there, big part of your decision will be the language you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand, just wanted hint from more experienced people. I will look on net for tutorial and stuff.

Comment: As said, it depends on your guidlines. There are many crossplatform languages such as Java and python, C# in .net core and many more. There's no general "best" language without knowing all the conditions, read up on the complexity of the problem. Maybe you already have some programming experiences, then it'll easier to do that in the language you know.

Comment: Have you considered making it a web app? Then it'll work on most platforms and devices.

Comment: No , I don't want it to be a web app. As I plan to use it offline on windows PC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to compile Windows binaries on a Linux machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1516690/608639), [How to compile for Windows on Linux with gcc/g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2033997/608639), [How to compile C code in Linux to run on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44670209/608639), [How to compile C++ on linux for to make a windows binary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9243687/608639), etc.

Comment: One more option is use platform independent IDEs like QT creator if you are using c++ or write just write a JAVA application

Comment: Xojo runs on Linux and can be used to make Windows GUI apps (and Mac and web apps for that matter). It's pretty easy to use so might be an option if you're a beginner. http://www.xojo.com