# Compile file in linux and run in windows

Tags: c, linux, windows, compilation

I start to learn c and c++ programming and I write it in Linux.

Can I make binary file with g++ and run it as exe in window 7? or i need to compile the code in windows again?

Comment: Yes, but doing so requires at lot of expertise

Comment: You need to compile it on Windows - its the easiest solution

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033997/howto-compile-for-windows-on-linux-with-gcc-g

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a mingw cross compiler to build windows binaries in linux. In Ubuntu (and I guess other Debian variants as well) the package is called `mingw32`. You then have a cross compiler under the name `i586-mingw32msvc-g++` (or similar). For building simple command line programs without library dependencies this is an OK solution.

If you need more then this I'd recommend you use [MXE](http://mxe.cc/) (M cross environment). MXE installs its own cross compiler and can build many libraries for you so you don't need to care about how to build the library dependencies.

For example the [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/) project (a 3D CAD program that is using Qt for its GUI) is using MXE for building the Windows releases. See [this page on the OpenSCAD wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Cross-compiling_for_Windows_on_Linux_or_Mac_OS_X) for a description of the build process.