# C++11 compiler for MS Windows in Linux environment

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, boost

I have a horrible time with C++ programming on Windows.

I can't link to `Boost` library.

Now, I am thinking about compiling my `cpp` programs in Ubuntu and run it on Windows.

Despite `i586-mingw32msvc-g++` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033997/h) works for many people. It is not a good solution for me as it is older than `C++11` and I cannot use it with boost library.

Is there any alternative method?

Comment: How would you test and run your program? You'll need Windows for that...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I will run it on my other laptop which is running windows

Comment: Can't you code for Linux?

Comment: You can use `i686-w64-mingw32-g++`, in Ubuntu trusty it is gcc version 4.8.4, and has quite good support for C++11. In Ubuntu Wily, it has gcc version 4.9.2, which is very good. Many people use this compiler successfully for windows, and you can target both 32 bit windows and 64 bit windows. You can run programs in wine also as preliminary, and then run them on windows later.

Comment: You could test it using Wine, too. Still, I'd suggest you fix the linking problems on the native system, it's not like Boost is some kind of seldom-used, obscure backyard-library.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I wish but my other softwares are limiting me to windows.

Comment: This seems like a total [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/166663) to me. Just fix your Boost issues on Windows, building Boost is about as trivial as it gets unless you want to do PGO/LTCG.

Comment: @ildjarn It worths trying. However after a few weeks trying, i am under pressure of time

Comment: Why would it simplify things to add an extra complication?

Comment: @ar2015 Why don't you post a question about your Boost issues?

Comment: @molbdnilo do you have any idea about this problem? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690733/c)

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install g++-mingw-w64-i686
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
```