# Compile simple C executable on Mac to run on Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, clang, cross-compiling

I have a simple C program that uses only basic stdio calls (single-threaded file I/O), which I compile on a Mac under clang.

Will this run under Windows? If not, how do I compile it to run under Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Howto compile for Windows on Linux with gcc / g++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033997/howto-compile-for-windows-on-linux-with-gcc-g)

Comment: That question addressed compiling from Linux using gcc. My question involves compiling from a Mac using clang. I don't understand why you believe these are duplicates.

Comment: You could install `VirtualBox` for free and install Windows in there and compile it without sullying your Mac with any Microsoft software.

Comment: @kdog Just read it. The same cross-compiler toolchain is available for both. The minute details of how to install it may be different, but that's easy enough to research given the name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ELLCC](http://ellcc.org), a clang based compiler toolchain, to cross compile Windows and Linux executables on a Mac.