# How to compile a .cpp file into a Windows executable (.exe) file in Linux

Tags: c++, executable, exe, cross-compiling

I make this program in C++ using Code::Blocks on Ubuntu. I need to turn it into a Windows executable binary (.exe file), but I don't know how to do this. Is it possible?

Comment: possible dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702945/compiling-windows-binaries-from-ubuntu

Comment: Why would you want a .exe file on Ubuntu?  Do you want to cross-compile for Windows?

Comment: I want to create a .exe file because the program will be tested on Windows. I just hate Windows so I don't use it.

Comment: @user69514: Now that's a very different question from what I thought you asked... I've slightly changed the question to reflect this.

Comment: Why don't you install Code::Blocks on Windows and compile it there? It's supposed to be a cross-platform IDE, after all.

Comment: When I compress a file in Unbutun it gives me an option for .exe as file extension. I'm wondering if this would be a valid conversion

Comment: Actually I just remember I have XP installed in Sun's Virtual Box. Let me try doing there

Comment: I suspect that'd create a self-extracting zip file, not convert your executable for Windows.

Comment: Yeah I installed bloodshed on the virtual machine xp. it worked fine.
thanks all

Answer (score 4):

If you meant, compiling an executable for Windows on Linux you might find some pointers on how to do that [here](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Cross-Compiling_Under_Linux).

Answer (score 3):

Both the MinGW32 distribution of GCC and Wine should be available for your distribution.

[MinGW has instructions](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LinuxCrossMinGW) and [winegcc](http://wiki.winehq.org/winegcc_pl) wraps a similar compiler that comes with the Wine distribution.

I've used both to compile both applications and libraries for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You could read [here](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Cross_Compiling_wxWidgets_Applications_on_Linux) on how to compile wxWidget applications on Linux for Windows using Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly unusual question. What you're asking is that you want to develop on Ubuntu, but the target platform is Windows?

My guess is that you have an assignment to turn in. My belief is that you should go to a lab and compile it and make sure it's working.

However, doing some research, you should try mingw at http://www.mingw.org/